# jQueryUI draggable stick with corners

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

How can I make an item draggable with custom some limits. It should be remain with in box. But parent have smaller size from child. Let me explain
Here is playground

```js
new ScrollZoom($('.parent'),20,0.5)
    $('.child').draggable();
```

```css
.parent {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      border: 1px solid;
      margin: auto;
    }
    .child {
      width: 380px;
      height: 380px;
      background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://techeak.com/zoominout.js"></script>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">
        
      </div>
    </div>
```

Left corner of child should be stick with left corner of parent.
[image]

And right with right of parent.
[image]

And same with top bottom.

PS: Scroll up down on child element to zoom in out
I'm trying to code feature like this
https://zegami.com/collections/public-5d7d31a84a1e710001f3a1c8?pan=FILTERS_PANEL&view=grid

Comment: This is very unclear. It sounds like you want `child` to be the handle for `parent`. In this way, when you move `child`, `parent` is moved with it?

Comment: No, child is zoomed via CSS

Comment: Run snippet and check

Comment: I ran the snippet before making my comment and it was unclear what is not working or what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guessing you are trying to make a Zoom Reticle of sorts. The Zoom In Out script you are using does not have a good way to tie into events when an object is zoomed. This makes getting the scale a bit harder. It can be done by examining the CSS of the `child` element.

Using this scale, you can just adjust the Draggable Containment.

> Constrains dragging to within the bounds of the specified element or region. Multiple types supported:
>
> - **Selector:** The draggable element will be contained to the bounding box of the first element found by the selector. If no element is found, no containment will be set.
> - **Element:** The draggable element will be contained to the bounding box of this element.
> - **String:** Possible values: `"parent"`, `"document"`, `"window"`.
> - **Array:** An array defining a bounding box in the form `[ x1, y1, x2, y2 ]`.

For this snippet, we will use the Array format to manage the `left` and `top` of the `child` for containment within the 4 boundaries. This will get changed whenever the `child` is zoomed. This example focuses on the left and right containment and can be expanded to manage top and bottom.

```js
$(function() {
  function getBounds(tObj) {
    var t = tObj.position().top;
    var l = tObj.position().left + parseInt(tObj.css("margin-left"));
    var b = t + tObj.height();
    var r = l + tObj.width();
    return [l, t, r, b];
  }

  function getScale(tObj) {
    var c = tObj.css("transform");
    var p = c.split(", ");
    var s = parseFloat(p[3]);
    return s;
  }

  function calcCont(tObj) {
    var b = getBounds(tObj);
    var child = tObj.children()[0];
    var s = getScale($(child)) || 1;
    var n = [
      b[0],
      b[1],
      b[2],
      b[3]
    ];
    if (s > 1) {
      n[0] = b[2] - ($(child).width() * s);
      n[2] = b[0];
    }
    return n;
  }
  new ScrollZoom($('.parent'), 20, 0.5);
  $('.child').draggable({
    containment: calcCont($(".parent"))
  });
  $(".parent").on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e) {
    $(".child").draggable("option", "containment", calcCont($(".parent")));
    return true;
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}

.parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: auto;
}

.child {
  width: 380px;
  height: 380px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://techeak.com/zoominout.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @IbrahimCh yes, I stated, "*this example focuses on the left and right containment and can be expanded to manage top and bottom.*"